# Применение регулярных выражений в MySQL запросе на удаление

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, mysql

И снова, Здравствуйте =))

Есть база, в одной из таблиц дата и время:

```
2012-09-20 21:52:11
2012-09-20 22:29:52
2012-09-20 22:31:26
2012-09-20 22:34:05
2012-09-20 22:37:05
2012-09-20 22:51:38
```

Нужно удалить записи по дате, только по дате, пробую так:

```
$DeleteDate = $_POST['deletedate'];
if($DeleteDate){
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE date = '$DeleteDate'");
}
```

Но, так удаляет только если вводить полностью дату и время. Хотел подставить регулярку, но не получается.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE date = '$DeleteDate' REGEXP '\s\S.*'")
```

Comment: А тип у колонки date какой?

Comment: А если попробовать так:

`DELETE FROM `table` WHERE date < '$DeleteDate 23:59:59' AND date > '$DeleteDate 00:00:00` ?

Comment: alexlz:
`date` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL

Получилось так:
"DELETE FROM `table` WHERE date LIKE '$DeleteDate%'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, **LIKE '%$DeleteDate%'** - это тоже регулярка. А **REGEXP** или его синоним **RLIKE** - работают медленнее, чем тот же **LIKE**.

Кстати, там синтаксис должен быть как-то так:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `date` REGEXP '^$DeleteDate'
```